# Disable or Disallow "zero" values in "DatePicker"?

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

I am trying to create a simple registration form on my website.

For the "Date of Birth" attribute, I'm using :

```
    <input type="date">
```

Everything's working fine......except for one annoying detail : the field (date-picker) allows the user to manually input the value for day, month and year.

Which means, the user can write :  "**0000**" as his year of birth.

I've searched online for a way to prevent this, but did not find anything remotely helpful.

Right now, I am using the "Max" attribute to ensure that the user is over the age of 18  (I did this by setting the "Max" attribute to the value :  Current_Date minus 18 years).

For example : today is 13th October, 2015.  Hence, the max value that the user can enter as his date of birth is :  **13th October, 1997**.

Unfortunately, this does not take care of the MINIMUM value.  It's possible to register one's date of birth as :  13th October, 0000.

How can I resolve this?

Of course, I could simply set a minimum value of, say :  13th October, 1915  (meaning : you need to be a minimum of 18 years old, and a maximum of 100 years old)

Obviously, this is silly!

Comment: why is this silly? how would you do it overwise?

Comment: A date of 0001 or even 1000 is equally "dumb" ... so you're going to have to set a low-end somehow ...

Comment: Maybe it's because I assumed there would be a way to resolve this without restricting Centenereans from registering   LOL  )))

Comment: Why not set the maximum age to be 130 years old, since that the oldest person ever was 122? That way you're not restricting anyone.

Comment: @Chris :  Thanks for your helpful reply :)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to adding the `max` attribute, try adding `min` as well.

MDN article on `input`, with `min` explained: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-min

You could also look into using jQuery to validate form inputs. One useful jQuery plugin for this is the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)